# Spigot API - Player Visibility Toggle Not Working

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create a plugin for a hub server that toggles visibility. Like Hypixel, or really any other semi-popular server with a hub.

Main Class:

```
package com.infxnty.HubCore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    private static Main Instance;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        setInstance(this);

        String text = "&1&lHubCore Enabled! &8» &aCoded by &b&lInfxnty";

        System.out.println(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', text));

        this.getConfig().options().copyDefaults();
        saveDefaultConfig();

        getCommand("star").setExecutor(new StarCommand(this));
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Gamemode(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }


    String serverone = this.getConfig().getString("Serverone");
    String servertwo = this.getConfig().getString("Servertwo");
    String serverthree = this.getConfig().getString("Serverthree");
    String guititle = this.getConfig().getString("GUI-Title");
    /* Array Lists */
    ArrayList<Player> enabled = new ArrayList<>();

    /* Star UI */

    public void applyStarUI(Player player) {

        // Beginning 
        Inventory gui = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', guititle));

        // Lores
        List<String> factionsLore = new ArrayList<>();
        factionsLore.add(" ");
        factionsLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click to connect");
        factionsLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "to " + servertwo + "!");

        List<String> cannoningLore = new ArrayList<>();
        cannoningLore.add(" ");
        cannoningLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click to connect");
        cannoningLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "to " + serverone + "!");

        List<String> eventsLore = new ArrayList<>();
        eventsLore.add(" ");
        eventsLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "Click to connect");
        eventsLore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "to " + serverthree + "!");

        // ItemStacks


        ItemStack cannoning;
        ItemMeta cannoningMeta;
        cannoning = new ItemStack(Material.DISPENSER);
        cannoningMeta = cannoning.getItemMeta();

        cannoningMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_RED + serverone);
        cannoningMeta.setLore(cannoningLore);
        cannoning.setItemMeta(cannoningMeta);


        ItemStack factions;
        ItemMeta factionsMeta;
        factions = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
        factionsMeta = factions.getItemMeta();

        factionsMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_RED + servertwo);
        factionsMeta.setLore(factionsLore);
        factions.setItemMeta(factionsMeta);


        ItemStack events;
        ItemMeta eventsMeta;
        events = new ItemStack(Material.FIREWORK);
        eventsMeta = events.getItemMeta();

        eventsMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_RED + serverthree);
        eventsMeta.setLore(eventsLore);
        events.setItemMeta(eventsMeta);

        // Inventory Setting

        gui.setItem(0, cannoning);
        gui.setItem(4, factions);
        gui.setItem(8, events);

        // Final

        player.openInventory(gui);

    }

    public static Main getInstance() {
        return Instance;
    }

    public static void setInstance(Main instance) {
        Instance = instance;
    }

}
```

Gamemode Class:

```
package com.infxnty.HubCore;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntitySpawnEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.FoodLevelChangeEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerDropItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerRespawnEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import com.infxnty.HubCore.Main;

public class Gamemode implements Listener {     

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        e.getPlayer().setMaxHealth(2.0);
        e.getPlayer().setHealth(2.0);

        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        int slot = 0;
        int slot2 = 8;

        ItemStack star;
        ItemMeta starMeta;
        star = new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR);
        starMeta = star.getItemMeta();

        starMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Server Selector");
        star.setItemMeta(starMeta);

        ItemStack visibility;
        ItemMeta visibilityMeta;
        visibility = new ItemStack(Material.SLIME_BALL);
        visibilityMeta = visibility.getItemMeta();

        visibilityMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Player Visibility Enabled!");
        visibility.setItemMeta(visibilityMeta);

        // Setting item in their inventory
        p.getInventory().setItem(slot, star);
        p.getInventory().setItem(slot2, visibility);

        }

        String serverone = Main.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Serverone");
        String servertwo = Main.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Servertwo");
        String serverthree = Main.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Serverthree");
        String guititle = Main.getInstance().getConfig().getString("GUI-Title");


        @EventHandler
        public void onPlayerClickInv(InventoryClickEvent e) {

        Player player = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();

        Inventory Inv = e.getClickedInventory();

        // Clicked inventory obj

        ItemStack visibility = new ItemStack(Material.SLIME_BALL);
        ItemStack star = new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR);

        // Title of the inventory (container.inventory is the name of a default player inventory)
        if(Inv.getTitle().equals("container.inventory")){
            if (e.getCurrentItem().isSimilar(visibility)) {
                e.setCancelled(true);
            }
        // Checking if clicked item is your compass or anything else
        if(e.getCurrentItem().isSimilar(star)) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
            }


        if (ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', e.getClickedInventory().getTitle()).equals(guititle)) {
            if (e.getCurrentItem() != null) {
            e.setCancelled(true);

                switch (e.getCurrentItem().getType()) {
                case DISPENSER:
                    player.performCommand("server " + serverone);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Sending you to our " + serverone + "Server!");
                    break;
                case DIAMOND_SWORD:
                    player.performCommand("server " + servertwo);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Sending you to our " + servertwo + "Server!");
                    break;
                case FIREWORK:
                    player.performCommand("server " + serverthree);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Sending you to our " + serverthree + "Server!");
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
                }

            player.closeInventory();
        }

        }
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @EventHandler
    public void onRespawn(PlayerRespawnEvent e) {
        e.getPlayer().setMaxHealth(2.0);
        e.getPlayer().setHealth(2.0);

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onDrop(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
        e.setCancelled(true);

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntitySpawn(EntitySpawnEvent e) {
        e.setCancelled(true);

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onFoodChange(FoodLevelChangeEvent e) {
        e.setCancelled(true);

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onDamage(EntityDamageEvent e) {
        e.setCancelled(true);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    @EventHandler
    public void onClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {

        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        int slot = 8;

        ItemStack visibility;
        ItemMeta visibilityMeta;
        visibility = new ItemStack(Material.SLIME_BALL);
        visibilityMeta = visibility.getItemMeta();

        visibilityMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Player Visibility Enabled!");
        visibility.setItemMeta(visibilityMeta);

        ItemStack visibility3;
        ItemMeta visibility3Meta;
        visibility3 = new ItemStack(Material.FIREBALL);
        visibility3Meta = visibility3.getItemMeta();

        visibility3Meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GRAY + "Player Visibility Disabled");
        visibility3.setItemMeta(visibility3Meta);

        if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.NETHER_STAR)) {
            p.performCommand("star");

        }

        if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.SLIME_BALL)) {
            p.getInventory().setItem(slot, visibility3);

        }

        if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.FIREBALL)) {
            p.getInventory().setItem(slot, visibility);

        }

    }

}
```

When right clicking the slime ball in game, it changes to the proper item, then instantly changes back. If you'd like to see it in game, please join my test server, as I may have not properly described it.

IP: 172.93.238.170:28584 (Version 1.11.2)

For anyone who is confused as to what the Spigot API is, it is for Minecraft. If you could please provide what line of code I have messed up, and how to change it, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide your code here, not inside an external link. Besides that, nobody here is likely to join your server just for testing it. You should make your answer clear enough for it to be understandable

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is you are switching the slime ball in your code then on the next few line you are switching it back.

This:

```
    if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.NETHER_STAR)) {
        p.performCommand("star");

    }

    if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.SLIME_BALL)) {
        p.getInventory().setItem(slot, visibility3);

    }

    if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.FIREBALL)) {
        p.getInventory().setItem(slot, visibility);

    }
```

Should be changed to this:

```
    if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.NETHER_STAR)) {
        p.performCommand("star");

    }else if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.SLIME_BALL)) {
        p.getInventory().setItem(slot, visibility3);

    }else if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.FIREBALL)) {
        p.getInventory().setItem(slot, visibility);

    }
```

Basically you were changing the slime ball to the fire ball and the next piece of code would change the fire ball back to the slime ball. Adding in the else statements made it where if the item was changed it would not check the rest of the items in your if statements. Hope that makes sense!